# Get value from select angularJs and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am currently working on a CRM in angularJs and Firebase, but I need to get the variable from an `ng-repeat` such follows

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option value="">--Choose an Account--</option>
    <option class="dropdown" value="{{contact.account}}" ng-repeat="account in accounts">{{account.name}}</option>
</select><br />
```

Controller

```
 $scope.addConct = function () {
    var account = $scope.contact.account;
```

The `accounts.name` is working fine, it shows all the accounts. How can I get that account string and assign that String to my `contact.account`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the ngModel directive to the select field to bind the value to a scope variable:

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="someVariable">
    <option value="">--Choose an Account--</option>
    <option class="dropdown" value="{{contact.account}}" ng-repeat="account in accounts">{{account.name}}</option>
</select><br />
```

Controller

```
$scope.someVariable = '';

$scope.addConct = function () {
    var account = $scope.contact.account;
};
```

Now you can access the value at any time with `$scope.someVariable`

More information on [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: I need to do it before selecting the the option.